# Unity3D static bool value not updating when manipulating from another script c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making my first game, and I am having trouble updating a bool value using a toggle button.

This is the button:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;
using Assets.Code.Scripts;
using Assets.Code.PowerPlants;

namespace Assets.Code.States

public void ShowIt()
{
    HydroElectric.t1Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 55, 100, 50), HydroElectric.t1Bool, "Turbina 2 MW");
    GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 100, 60, 80, 25), HydroElectric.prod.ToString ()); // PRODUCED ENERGY 
}
```

This is where I have the if condition:

```
using System;

namespace Assets.Code.PowerPlants

public class HydroElectric
{
    public static bool t1Bool = true;
    public int turbina1;
    public static float prod = 0;

    public HydroElectric ()
    {
        if (t1Bool == true)
        {
            turbina1 = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            turbina1 =0;
        }

        prod = turbina1;
    } 
}
```

I have no errors on the console, the bool value is changing (I used debug) but the value of turbina1 is not changing (when I debug it from the first script). I have no idea why its value is not changing along with the true or false condition. Any idea?

Comment: `prod` is equal to `turbinal`. `turbinal` is equal to 0 when `t1Bool` is false. `t1Bool` is true by default. The only way `prod` could be equal to 0 is if `t1Bool` was modified from true to false. Clearly `t1Bool` is being updated; it just may be that `t1Bool` is always being updated to false.

Comment: I used debugger and the t1Bool is changing everytime I click on the button. I debugged turbina1 and is always equal to zero.

Comment: Place a breakpoint in the .ctor here: `turbina1 = 2;` and one here: `prod = turbina1;` - step through the code and you'll see both values.

Comment: Are you intending for `t1Bool` to be changed not only at the very start? If so, your `if` block should be placed after your button code instead.

Currently the `if` block is contained in the constructor for `HydroElectric`, which will never be called again after initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public HydroElectric ()` is a default constructor. It is executed only when you instantiate a new HydroElectric instance using `new HydroElectric()`. You never do it. This is why the code inside this function is never actually called.

Furthermore, not in general case but specifically with MonoBehaviour, it is not a good practice to use constructors at all since in best case it will be called once and then immediately overwritten by scene serialization. See more: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/32413/using-constructors-in-unity-c.html

If what you want to achieve is executing your code each time you change t1Bool for example, you can make it a property:

```
public class HydroElectric
{
  //.... Your other code
  //....
  public static bool T1Bool {
    get{
      return t1Bool;
    }
    set{
      t1Bool = value;
      if (t1Bool == true)
      {
        turbina1 = 2;
      }
      else
      {
        turbina1 =0;
      }

      prod = turbina1;
    }
  }
}

//...
// Usage
HydroElectric.T1Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 55, 100, 50), HydroElectric.T1Bool, "Turbina 2 MW");
```